# libsodium.so.23 when using SSR in ubuntu 16

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, libsodium, great-firewall-of-china

I'm trying to use shadowsocksR in my ubuntu 16 .

1. sudo apt-get install git
2. git clone -b manyuser https://github.com/shadowsocksr-backup/shadowsocksr.git
3. cd shadowsocksr/shadowsocks
4. python local.py -s server_ip -p server_port -k password -m chacha20-ietf -o tls1.2_ticket_auth

then he said " libsodium not found" so I install libsodium

1. download the LATEST.tar.gz from  https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/
2. tar -zxf  LATEST.tar.gz
3. cd libsodium-stable
4. ./configure
5. make && make check
6. sudo make install
   ```

but this time

python local.py -s server_ip -p server_port -k password -m chacha20-ietf -o tls1.2_ticket_auth

He said OSError: libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

---

[image: details]

---

thankyou for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to install libsodium-dev
Try running "apt-get install libsodium-dev"

Answer (score 1):

If you've compiled libsodium, make sure libsodium is in the linker cache:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libsodium
```

If there is no output, chances are that the linker cache is not updated in time.

You can update the cache by:

```
sudo ldconfig
```